# Is there any way something like this possible?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
<?php
$division=$row['mark'];
$pass="Passed";
if($division>=80 && $pass==include "result.php")// Result.php has two value: one is `Pass` and the other is `Fail`.
{
  echo "Letter";
}
elseif($division>=70 && $pass==include "result.php")
{
  echo "First";
}
else
{
  echo "Fail";
}
?>
```

What I want to output here is: if `$division` is equal to 80 and at the same time if `$pass` is equal to `Passed`, echo `Letter`. But if `$division` is less than 70, echo `Fail`; also `$pass` here equals to `fail` which is taken from `result.php`.  I have been trying to output it with following code, but it does not work. It outputs `FailFailFailFail` when `$division` is less than 70.

Code for Result.php

```
<?php
   $eng=40;
   $mizo=40;
   $hindi=40;
   $maths=40;
   $ss=40;
   $science=40;

   if ($eng>=40 && $mizo>=40 && $hindi>=40 && $maths>=40 && $ss>=40 && $science>=40)
   {
   echo "<font color=green>Passed</font>";
   }
   else 
   {
   echo "<font color=red>Failed</font>";
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you move `$pass=include "result.php"` above the if-statements?

Comment: You don't say anything about "First" in your description. Is it necessary?

Comment: show what's in result.php

Comment: what does code for result.php look like. Can you include it only once at the top of the page and then use a function in result.php to return the values in say $return variable and then perform the condition checking on that ?

Comment: Uh, why should it NOT say fail when $division is less than 70? That's how you've written the code. only if division is 70 or GREATER will it output letter/first, otherwise it should say fail.

Comment: $Jack As I said `include.php` can output two different things `Pass` and `Fail`. If I put this above the if statement, how can I use here in the If Statement?

Comment: $Maximus2012 I will update the post and include the code of result.php.

Comment: If include is outputing something then you're doing the wrong thing. It should output nothing, but either have a single word in it (no other code), or store its result in a variable ready for use by the script that calls it.

Comment: @Marc B, when $division is less than 70 it will output `Failed`. But if $division is more than or equal to 70 it will output `First` and not `Passed`. No one still gives me the expected solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will do. For your result.php, use the following:

```
 <?php
 $eng= 40;
 $mizo= 40; 
 $hindi= 40; 
 $maths= 40; 
 $ss= 40; 
 $science= 40; 

//  first group your variable into one array = $all
$all = array($eng, $mizo, $hindi, $maths, $ss, $science); 
// second, just iterate over them till you find one value -40
for($i=0; $i < count($all); $i++){
if($all[$i] < 40) $sum = 1;
}
?>
```

For output:

```
<?php include "result.php";?>
<?php 
$division=$row_['mark'];
$pass="Passed";
$test = (!empty($sum)) ? 'Failed' : 'Passed';
if($division>=80 && $pass==$test)
{
echo "Letter";
}
elseif($division>=70 && $pass==$test)
{
echo "First"; 
}
else
{
echo "Passed";
}
?>
```

Comment: how can you come up with such a very good solution. It's beautiful and short and handles everything I want properly. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this all the wrong way. You can't compare the results of an include like that, not to mention they don't match properly anyway as you're comparing a single word string against a string with a whole bunch of HTML in it.

A better way to do it is to include results.php and store your answer in a variable. I have written an example below.

**First off you need to change result.php to:**

```
<?php
$eng=40;
$mizo=40;
$hindi=40;
$maths=40;
$ss=40;
$science=40;

if ($eng>=40 && $mizo>=40 && $hindi>=40 && $maths>=40 && $ss>=40 && $science>=40)
{
    $test = "Passed";
}
else 
{
    $test = "Failed";
}
?>
```

**Then you put the following in the first file:**

```
<?php
$division=$row['mark'];
$pass="Passed";
include("result.php");// Result.php has two value: one is `Pass` and the other is `Fail`, store in $test.
if($division>=80 && $pass==$test)
{
  echo "Letter";
}
elseif($division>=70 && $pass==$test)
{
  echo "First";
}
else
{
  echo "Fail";
}
?>
```

Comment: $Styphon I will test your script and let you know how it comes. Thanks.

Comment: still there is some problem again. It echoes both `First` and `Failed`. Have you debugged your code? When Division is greater than 70 and less than 80, the expected output is only `First` and not `First` and `Failed` as your code does output. There might be some tricks.

Comment: It can't output both, it's an if statement. As soon as one outputs that is the end of the statement. You must be echoing it elsewhere.

Comment: I have just recheck your code and see that it works also. The problem with me is I use `<font>` inside `result.php` and not use the tag in `$pass='Passed'` Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the file first:

```
<?php

include "result.php"; //include the file

$division =$ row['mark'];
$pass = "Passed";

if($division == 80 && $pass == "Passed") {
  echo "Letter";
}

elseif($division < 70) {
  echo "Fail";
}

?>
```

Comment: I think you've missunderstood what he's trying to accomplish. He wants to test the output of result.php against what is in $pass.